# js variable and radio button checked / unchecked

Tags: jquery, html

```
<input id='rb1' type="radio" name="bafter" checked>
<input id='rb2' type="radio" name="bafter">
```

js

```
$(".item").click(function(){
    console.log(a); // 39 (that's ok)
    if ($('#rb1').prop('checked') == true) {a -=1;}
    else {a +=1;}
});

console.log(a);
```

If `rb1` checked result is - 38 (ok)
If `rb2` is not checked reusult is - 391 (should be 40)

Any help?

Comment: Where is `a` defined?

Comment: @Vandesh, wherever. For example at the top of script.

Comment: I can't see any problem in [**your code**](https://jsfiddle.net/4uvhzrun/).

Comment: @Mohammad, 39 -1 is 38, and not 39.

Comment: @bonaca - Can you include that in the code? What may be happening is it gets evaluated as a string. And Hence 39+1 is getting converted to 391. `string` + `int` in Javascript = `string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a might be getting evaluated as a string.
And `string` + `int` = `string` in Javascript
So, "39" + 1 = "391"
Use `a = parseInt(a) + 1;` and `a = parseInt(a) - 1;`

Comment: That's it. Have you any link about harmful `eval` function ?

Comment: Why eval is harmful? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 2):

It is concatenating as a string. 
Try `a =eval("a+1")`

Comment: but it should not be concatenated !

Comment: Yes, but JavaScript takes "+" as string concatenator.

Comment: I will. be patient, pls

Comment: eval is harmful and not recommended to be used. Here's why - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea